# Domain of function is not correctly evaluated by WolframAlpha?

Tags: functions

The domain of function $$\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x+2}}+\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{1+x}}}$$ should be $-\infty < x < -2$ and $-2 < x < -1$ and $-1 < x < \infty$.

When calculation it with WolframAlpha it gives [empty domain](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain%20of%20f%28x%29=Sqrt%28%28x-2%29/%28x%2b2%29%29%2bSQRT%28%281-x%29/SQRT%281%2bx%29%29), however when [plotting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20f%28x%29=Sqrt%28%28x-2%29/%28x%2b2%29%29%2bSQRT%28%281-x%29/SQRT%281%2bx%29%29%20x%20from%20-4%20to%204) this function it's clear that it's has not empty domain. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your domain is given by the intervals $(-\infty,-2) \cap (-2,-1) \cap (-1,\infty)$. Notice that this intersection is empty. I believe that your plot on Wolfram is showing you a plot over the complex numbers. Notice though that none of the points on the plot have imaginary part of zero. So there are no real numbers in the domain.

Answer (score 2):

Well, WolframAlpha is plotting a complex-valued plot. Certainly the domain of this function is nonempty if we are viewing this as a complex valued function. However, it appears you're viewing this as a real valued function.

We can compute the domain pretty easily. First, since you have $\sqrt{1+x}$, we need $x\geq -1$. Then for $$\sqrt{\dfrac{1-x}{\sqrt{1+x}}}$$ we need $x\leq 1$. Thus, we've limited our domain to be contained in $(-1,1]$. Finally for the other term, we need both $x-2$ and $x+2$ to be either positive or negative. For the former, we need $x$ in $[2,\infty)$. For the latter, $(-\infty, -2)$.

Now, here's the issue: $(-1,1]$ does not intersect $(-\infty,-2)\cup [2,\infty)$. Therefore, the domain is empty.